# Refresh <Routes> Component in react-router v6 after successful login and logout

Tags: reactjs, redirect, routes, react-router

I'm facing two problems in implementing Routes and Navigation in `React` application and I'm using `react-router-dom` v6 library for routing purposes.

**First issue:** When I'm logged I should be redirected to `Dashboard page` using programmatic redirect which is not working. as my `<Routes>` component is still getting old user object for user which is null before login. `<Routes>` component should refresh after successful login to get valid user object.

**Second issue:** (it is low priority but still) Menu label `Login` is not changed to `Logout` as it is separate component and I don't want to use some props to refresh back, need some intelligent way to take same effect and Login should be changed to Logout automatically without worrying about props and all that.

Code structure is below:

**App.jsx**

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="main_page_wrapper">
            <MainNavigation />
            <AppRouter />
        </div>
    );
}
export default App
```

**MainNavigation.jsx**

```
function MainNavigation() {
    const logout = () => {
        localstorage.setItem('user', null);
    }
    return (
        <div className="site_nav_lists">
            <ul className="main_navigation_list">
                <li><NavLink to={'/'} title="Home">Home</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink to={'/dashboard'} title="Dashboard">Dashboard</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink to={'/contact'} title="Contact">Contact</NavLink></li>
            </ul>
            <ul className="user_navigation_list">
                {
                    localstorage.getItem(user) ? 
                    <li><NavLink title="Logout" onClick={logout}>Logout</NavLink></li> : 
                    <li><NavLink to={'/login'} title="Login">Login</NavLink></li> 
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
export default MainNavigation
```

**AppRouter.jsx**

```
const AppRouter = () => {
    const loggedInUser = localstorage.getItem('user'); // this should be refreshed on successful login
    return (
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route element={<ProtectedRoute user={loggedInUser} />}>
          <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<Page404 />} />
      </Routes>
    );
}
export default AppRouter;
```

**Login.jsx**

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
function Login() {
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    const submitLoginForm = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (validEmail == true && validPassword == true) {
            let loggedInUser = { id: '1', name: 'John Doe' };
            localstorage.setItem('user', loggedInUser);
            navigate('/dashboard'); // this is giving 404
        }
        else {
            toast.error('Invalid username or password');
        }
    }
    return (<FormComponent />);
}
export default Login
```

Comment: What is your `ProtectedRoute`? That doesn't look right. I think the `path` (`/dashboard`) should be on the parent and the child should be `index`.

Comment: Also note that setting something in `localstorage` isn't a state change and won't cause a render. I'm not sure if that's the issue here since you `navigate` after (which is a state change) but your logout function won't work because the DOM won't update after the function runs.

Comment: @sallf 
`const ProtectedRoute = ({ user, children }) => {
    if(user) {
        return children ? children : <Outlet />;
    }
    return <Navigate to="/404" replace />;
};
export default ProtectedRoute;`

Comment: Localstorage is just store, every time I get something from this store I should get fresh data. AppRouter should be refreshed after login so I can get valid user which is set in login file.

Comment: "Localstorage is just store" what does that mean? You're using redux or context and changed it here? I think it's the issue. Log `user` and `localstorage.getItem('user')` in `ProtectedRoute` and I bet you'll get different values after login.

Comment: I'm not using Redux or Context, I'm just storing data in localstorage, 
I also debug user object before login and after login, which is updated inside localstorage but in AppRouter I'm still getting old user object (which is null) that's why in ProtectedRoute not getting user and getting 404.
main issue is how I can refresh AppRouter after login?
or my App Structure needs to be changed or something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256584/discussion-between-sallf-and-faisal-janjua).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes to `localstorage` aren't state changes and don't cause a re-render. You should refactor your code so that `user` is an object in state. [Context](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext) is a good solution for this as it makes it easy to pass a state value into any component, without needing a long `props` chain.

```
export const UserContext = createContext();

// App
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  return (
    <div className="main_page_wrapper">
      <UserContext.Provider value={{user, setUser}}>
        <MainNavigation />
        <AppRouter />
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

// AppRouter
const AppRouter = () => {
  const { user } = useContext(UserContext) 
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route element={<ProtectedRoute user={loggedInUser} />}>
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
      <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<Page404 />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

// Login
function Login() {
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  const { setUser } = useContext(UserContext);
  const submitLoginForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (validEmail == true && validPassword == true) {
      let user = { id: '1', name: 'John Doe' };
      setUser(user)
      navigate('/dashboard');
    } else {
      toast.error('Invalid username or password');
    }
  }
  return (<FormComponent />);
}
```